# Setup -N parameter in SSH Config File

Tags: linux, ssh

I would like to use the -N flag in my ssh config file, but I'm not sure how to do this?

Is it possible?

```
 -N      Do not execute a remote command.  This is useful for just for‐
         warding ports (protocol version 2 only).


Host foo
    HostName foo.bar.com
    User baz
    <how can I add -N flag here?>
```

Comment: Sounds like a case of the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/203101). What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: @terdon I am trying to pass the -N flag to ssh for a gitolite server my work has that appears to be slow during push/pull.  I was told this will stop ssh from executing a shell on startup and loading the environment and stuff which is contributing to the lag I'm experiencing.

Comment: Why don't you just run `ssh -N`, why do you need to set this as a config parameter?

Comment: Answered here https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/417373/69080. Try RemoteCommand cat

Answer (score 7):

Answered here https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/417373/69080. Starting in OpenSSH 7.6, there is an option called `RemoteCommand`.  Try adding to your config file:

```
RemoteCommand cat
```

When using this, I also like to also include:

```
LogLevel DEBUG
```

Comment: Nice one. I added `RemoteCommand echo "Tunneling through xxxxx machine. CTRL+C to terminate connection"; cat` to get some feedback.

Comment: Since I originally wrote this, instead of `cat`, I now prefer `sleep infinity` if the remote machine supports it.  Some old implementations of `sleep` might not support inifinity, so `sleep 86400` is probably good enough.  Another good option is `tail -f`.  Problem with `cat` is if you send an EOF (ctrl+d) on the input, it will close the tunnel, which you may or may not want.

Answer (score 5):

I know this question was asked for Linux but at least for macOS (Ventura 13), I can add `SessionType none` to any host I want and it works exactly as the flag -N. Hope this info is useful to someone :)

small edit: As it was pointed out in the comments above, I'm currently using `openSSH version 9.0p1`. Hope that's a little more general.

Comment: Big Linux distros use OpenSSH. Your solution [works in OpenSSH](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config#SessionType).

Comment: For the record, `SessionType` was introduced in [**OpenSSH 8.7**, released in **2021-08-20**](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-8.7): _"add a SessionType directive to `ssh_config`, allowing the configuration file to offer equivalent control to the `-N` (no session) and `-s` (subsystem) command-line flags."_

Answer (score 2):

Which OS? Do a man ssh_config and see if your ssh has such an option. On linux it this option is not available as a config parameter. As far as I know, I think the same is true with other openssh or similar clients in other platforms.

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04,  I looked at the ssh_config man page but unless I overlooked it I didn't see it possible.

Answer (score 2):

actually -N is not a parameter but just a flag like -l or else

if you don't want to have command ssh -N -l username HOSTNAME
you can create alias ssh = "ssh -N" (on the host from where you want to ssh to your gitolite server.

another idea that came to my mind , the slowness of ssh can be because of DNS also, on connection server is trying to resolve hostname of machine which is trying to connect and if there are a wrong entry in DNS or no info available it will become slow on connection

kinds